# Why Activity Indicator Not working In Xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am trying to display `ActivityIndicator` After I press a button while I am trying to update The Column Field On DataBase, it is not appearing? What is the problem?

On the following My Code:

```
ActivityIndicator ai = new ActivityIndicator()
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                Color = Color.Black
            };
            ai.IsRunning = true;
            ai.IsEnabled = true;
            ai.BindingContext = this;
            ai.SetBinding(ActivityIndicator.IsVisibleProperty, "IsBusy");

            ProcessToCheckOut = new Button { Text = "Set Inf" };
            ProcessToCheckOut.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                this.IsBusy = true;
                UserUpdateRequest user=new UserUpdateRequest();
                user.userId = CustomersPage.ID;
                appClient.UpdateInfo(user);                  
                this.IsBusy = false;
                Navigation.PushAsync(new CheckoutShippingAddressPage(appClient));
            };
         Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children={
                tb,
                ai,
                ProcessToCheckOut
                }
            };
```

Comment: How did you define IsBusy? Is it a Bindableproperty?

Comment: ProcessToCheckOut is button .. should i add a property ?!

Comment: @StarterPack IsBusy is built-in. It is used to turn the statusbar activity icon on and off - but you can also use it in your own code like is being done here

Answer (score 15, accepted):

None of the code between `this.IsBusy=true;` and `this.IsBusy=false;` is asynchronous. So what is happening is that you enable the indicator but then continue to do work on the main thread and then disable the indicator before the UI has a chance to update.

To fix this, you would need to put `appClient.UpdateInfo(user)` into an async code block (along with the PushAsync and disabling of activity indicator and probably some of the other code). If you don't have an async version of `UpdateInfo()` then you can push it off into a background thread... assuming whatever work it does is actually safe for running in a background thread.

```
ProcessToCheckOut.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    this.IsBusy = true;
    var id = CustomersPage.ID;
    Task.Run(() => {
        UserUpdateRequest user=new UserUpdateRequest();
        user.userId = id;
        appClient.UpdateInfo(user);
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            this.IsBusy = false;
            Navigation.PushAsync(new CheckoutShippingAddressPage(appClient));
        });
    });
};
```

Note that I also used `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` to marshal execution back to the main thread once the background work is done. This isn't always necessary but it is good practice.

Comment: Hi, I just want to share a slightly different approach I found and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43119987/1605873

Comment: Awesome! Out of so many search and following so many complicated codes, repeatedly again and again with few variations, not a single got clicked. But your so sweet simple code made the great magic for me which I was fighting since so many months! Thanks a ton!! Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => is probably must as without that the indicator stopped and navigation statement passed without actual navigation. But with the Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => implementation it worked smoothly. The Indicator stopped and navigation of page was executed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

your endoint must be getasync or postasync with await