# Xamarin Forms -> Activity Indicator not working if Commands of statements to be executed

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

**Using Visual Studio 2017 Community 15.8.1**

This is after going through all options of stackoverflow regarding ActivityIndicator. So though it may be a duplication but nothing is helping me out.
So finally decided to post my workouts and get best help from here.

**What I have tried till now:-**
1. {Binding IsLoading} + INotifyPropertyChanged + public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName) + IsLoading = true; concept.
2. ActivityIndicator_Busy.IsVisible = false; (Direct control accessed)

These two approaches were mostly recommended and I went into depth of each since lot of hours in last few weeks. But nothing got crack.

**What I achieved?:-**
ActivityIndicator_Busy.IsVisible = false; concept is working smooth only when I put return before executing the statements (for testing purpose); statement on Button Clicked event. (Attached Image)
But as soon as I remove the return; On Pressing Button, directly after some pause, the HomePage Opens.

**MY Questions:-**
1. This is particular with the current scenario how to get the ActivityIndicator run Immediately when user clicks the Welcome Button.
2. Pertaining to same, When app starts there is also a blank white screen coming for few seconds almost 30 seconds which I also I want to show ActivityIndicator. But dont know how to impose that logic at which instance.

**My Inputs**

**My MainPage.xaml File:-**
**(Edited 06-Sept-2018 09.11 pm)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage x:Name="page_main_page"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:appNutri"
             BindingContext="{x:Reference page_main_page}"
             x:Class="appNutri.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" 
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout>
                <Image x:Name="Image_Welcome" 
                       Source="welcome.png" 
                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       WidthRequest="300" 
                       HeightRequest="300" />
                <Button x:Name="Button_Welcome" 
                        Clicked="Button_Welcome_Clicked" 
                        Text="Welcome!" 
                        BackgroundColor="DeepSkyBlue" 
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        TextColor="White" 
                        HeightRequest="60" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" 
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <ActivityIndicator 
                        x:Name="ActivityIndicator_Busy"
                        Color="Black"
                        IsEnabled="True" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        IsRunning="{Binding Source={x:Reference page_main_page}, Path=IsLoading}" 
                        IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference page_main_page}, Path=IsLoading}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

My MainPage.cs Code:-
**(Edited on 06-Sept-2018 09.13 pm)**

```
using appNutri.Model;
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace appNutri
{
    public partial class MainPage : Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {

        private bool isLoading;

        public bool IsLoading
        {
            get
            {
                return isLoading;
            }

            set
            {
                isLoading = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsLoading");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
        {           
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));

            }
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        protected async void Button_Welcome_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IsLoading = true;

            await Select_Local_User_Information();

            IsLoading = false;
        }

        private async Task Select_Local_User_Information()
        {

            IsLoading = true;

            string where_clause = "";

            try
            {
                Sql_Common.Database_Folder_Path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

                string Database_Full_Path = Path.Combine(Sql_Common.Database_Folder_Path, Sql_Common.Database_Name);

                SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(Database_Full_Path);

                //connection.DropTable<User_Master>();
                //connection.Delete(connection.Table<User_Master>());
                //connection.CreateTable<User_Master>(CreateFlags.ImplicitPK | CreateFlags.AutoIncPK);

                connection.CreateTable<User_Master>();

                int count = connection.ExecuteScalar<int>("Select count(*) from User_Master");

                if (count == 0)
                {
                    connection.DropTable<User_Master>();
                    connection.CreateTable<User_Master>();

                    //IsLoading = false;
                    //IsBusy = false;

                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new User_Register_Page());

                }
                else
                {
                    Sql_Common.User_Logged = true;

                    var Local_User_Data = connection.Table<User_Master>().ToList();

                    User_Master.Logged_User_Details_Container.First_Name = Local_User_Data[0].First_Name;
                    User_Master.Logged_User_Details_Container.Cell1 = Local_User_Data[0].Cell1;

                    where_clause = " Upper ( First_Name ) = " + "'" + User_Master.Logged_User_Details_Container.First_Name.ToUpper().Trim() + "'" + " and " +
                                   " Cell1 = " + "'" + User_Master.Logged_User_Details_Container.Cell1.Trim() + "'";

                    int records = Sql_Common.Get_Number_Of_Rows_Count("User_Master", where_clause);

                    if (records == 0)
                    {
                        connection.DropTable<User_Master>();
                        connection.CreateTable<User_Master>();

                        IsLoading = false;

                        await Navigation.PushAsync(new User_Register_Page());

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        User_Master.User_Master_Table(where_clause, User_Master.Logged_User_Details_Container);

                        IsLoading = false;

                        await Navigation.PushAsync(new User_Home_Page());

                    }

                }

                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                string ex_msg = ex.Message;
            }

            IsLoading = false;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Working Image]

---

**04-Oct-2018**
**Finally resolved with [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008055/activity-indicator-not-working-xamarin-forms/)**

---

Comment: Could you please strip your code down to a [mcve]? It would be way easier to solve the issue without everything else around.

Comment: **As a side note:** You are concatenating your SQL statements by hand. This is SQLite and if the user wanted xe could access the data anyway, but if you accessed a real My- MS-, PostgreSQL database somewhere in the future, this will open the doors for SQLi attacs.

Comment: [New Query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52219398/10289226/) Just raised after your concerns and also one of previous suggestion from one user. A more detailed issues for same and any resolution would be highly appreciated. I wanted a separate discussion for same, hence not replied anymore here

Comment: **Another side note:** If you use the [`CallerMemberName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) attribute in your `RaisePropertyChanged` you don't have to write out the name of the property, but it's determined automatically by the compiler.

Comment: Please see if my updates helps you.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update 2018-09-10

You think that you have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` by adding `INotifyPropertyChanged` to your class definition and adding the event

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

along with its event invocator

```
public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
{           
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

Anyway, since `ContentPage` already implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, adding those did *not* implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. `ContentPage` already defines the event (or rather `BindableObject`from which `ContentPage` indirectly inherits). Any object that relies on being informed about property changes in your page will subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of the ancestor and not the `PropertyChanged` event you defined, hence the `ActivityIndicator` will not update.

Just remove the event you defined and call `OnPropertyChanged` instead of `RaisePropertyChanged()` and you should be fine.

```
private bool isLoading;

public bool IsLoading
{
    get
    {
        return isLoading;
    }

    set
    {
        isLoading = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Since `OnPropertyChanged` is declared as

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
```

you don't have to pass the property name by hand. The compiler will do that for you beacsue of the `CallerMemberNameAttribute`.

#### End Update

The XAML extension `{Binding IsLoading}` binds the `ActivityIndicator` to the `BindingContext` of your page. By default the `BindingContext` is `null`, hence there is nothing to bind to and all your efforts are to no avail.

### With a viewmodel

The preferred solution would be to use a viewmodel and assign it to `MainPage.BindingContext`, e.g.

```
var page = new MainPage()
{
    BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel()
}
```

but *if* you take that road, you should move all of your UI logic to that viewmodel and encapsulate your SQL access and business logic in other classes, to keep the viewmodel clean from resource accesses and business logic. Having the resource accesses and logic in code behind may work for that small example, but is likely to become an unmaintainable mess.

### Without a viewmodel

Anyway, you don't *have* to use a viewmodel to use bindings. You can set the `BindingContext` for the page (or some children) or use the `Source` of the `BindingExtension`

#### Setting the `BindingContext`

The `BindingContext` is passed from any page or view to it's children. You first have to give your page a name with `x:Name="Page"` (don't have to use `Page`, anyway, you can't use the class name of your page) and set the `BindingContext` to that page

```
<ContentPage ...
    x:Name="Page"
    BindingContext="{x:Reference Page}"
    ...>
```

now binding to `IsLoading` should work.

#### Using `Source` in the `Binding`

If you want to reference something else than the `BindingContext` of a view, `BindingExtension` has a property `Source`. You have to give a name to your page, too (see above)

```
<ContentPage ...
    x:Name="Page"
    ...>
```

and now you can reference this in your binding

```
<ActivityIndicator 
    ...
    IsRunning="{Binding Path=IsLoading, Source={x:Reference Page}}" 
    IsVisible="{Binding Path=IsLoading, Source={x:Reference Page}}"/>
```

Comment: Appreciate your quick recommendations in detail. I implemented as per your suggestions. In fact had already done that logic more than 3-4+ times with possible variations as much as I could. But your code had a additional suggestion for Setting the BindingContext, that I did not found anywhere.
Check updated code in XAML as well as cs files. Sad no luck! But you may find that I am calling 
private async Task Select_Local_User_Information() in Button Clicked event.
with await. Yes but if I put return; to test, it works. See if you can find any issue still left.

Comment: Would appreciate if you have any more inputs for improvements on my updated code. Probably I think I am very near with resolution with your detailed information provided.

Comment: I will Update my answer later today.

Comment: Hey, I couldn't make it today. It's still on my agenda to have a look at it.

Comment: @YeshwantMudholkar What do you mean by *"Yes but if I put return; to test, it works."*? Could you show the code that works and the code that does not, to understand better what went wrong?

Comment: Extremely Sorry I had updated that code. But even if you see in button click event if i put return; statement before the await Select_Local_User_Information(); then the ActivityIndicator is shown and if I remove it then it is not showing.
Even I had tried the toggle on/off 
if (IsLoading==true)   
     IsLoading=false;
else
   IsLoading=true;
This also works smooth. But any statement called after that then it does not work.

Comment: I tried OnPropertyChanged();
If I put breakpoint, as usual its going all way smooth hitting IsLoading = true. But on front end the ActivityIndicator is still invisible. I have set enabled property true at XAML only. But nothing is working. In fact this is just a testing part on Load, still I need to implement in a set of pages where it is mainly required to show app is busy and some data is retrieved.

Comment: I'll have another look at it.

Comment: Can I post a twisting code which works fine if I do not let the code pass the statements of code further (i.e. return;) and toggle ActivityIndicator true & false directly with the control?