# Xamarin Forms (Visual Studio 2017) Android. How much secure to store SQL Server Database credentials in App?

Tags: sql-server, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have already
1. Searched on google
2. Here on **stackoverflow**
3. Some recommendations for me on my posts, that not to use direct connections free text statements from App to SQL Server, rather than to use mostly recommended REST API services.

**Overview**
I find SQL Server connection very smooth in Xamarin Forms development. My major projects are web based asp.net c# and desktop based vb.net which use same Hosted MS SQL Server 2012 Express (Virtual Private Server and not shared server) Database.

In Desktop we have option such encrypting the app.Config file where we can store the database connection secure credentials.
In Web-based we have web.config file where we say its secured way to put credentials there.
**(If wrong please correct me)**
Frankly I tried at initial stage REST API Services including Microsoft Azure  but it looks very complex or some or other limitations for me in approach or pay strucure. (Or say may be I totally am now flexible in c# regular statements).
As I am having own Hosting Server I don't want to choose again any other.

**Finally to my query**
Now I store in Xamarin Forms Class folder in .cs all secure credentials.

```
/------------------------------------------
//Connection String
//------------------------------------------
public static string appNutri_connection_string = @"data source=<IP ADDRESS>;initial catalog=<Database_Name>;user id=<user_name>;password=<pass_word>;Connect Timeout=600"
```

And I use this appNutri_connection_string throughout project for connections.
Also when we compile the Package we are opted first to enter password before distribution.
Not only that before we upload it on Google Play, it rechecks Hash Key credentials respective package name, then only it publish the apk.

So please let me know how is not safe for APK to store credentials in .cs file. Secondly , most important is there any other solution to encrypt the credentials file? So that I do not need to break my so smooth trend going on all platforms.

**This is a very crucial stage for me to go further as still I am in very initial stage of product live implementation. So do not want to go further with any loop holes or wrong perception. Data (Client's especially) Security and Privacy is my major Task. Cannot compromise on that anytime. So please suggest me best way to achieve this task.**

***(Once again may be a possible duplicate question but frankly I did not found a detailed explanation or information nor here nor on any google search)***

Answer (score 4):

As you are in very initial stage of your product lifetime, PLEASE CHANGE YOUR ARCHITECTURE!
Never, nerver connect directly to a sensitive database from outside - put at least a front-end layer (eg. API) between public clients and your database.

Comment: Can you please mention whats the actual threat for same? and such material for same confirming? As I have just got alerts but no actual documentation on that even on google. So just trying to clear that doubt first. No doubt as I said I have now keep hold on further updates. Till I am convinced with a API or any other such tool, which will secure my data and I would be relax, I am not going to proceed at all.

Comment: Sorry but it is a very basic concept, covered by any discussion about security in software architecture. Topics are "attack surface reduction", data security (any information written on a client may - and will! - be public), "n-tier" architectures... These are really basic concept for a professionel